# After insert trigger to update account balance after doing deposit

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have two tables. One is information about the account and the other is information about new deposits. I want to write a trigger the updates the balance in account table after doing deposit in the deposit table. can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code that i wrote? I'm new in sql and try to learn. Thanks in advance!

```
create table account( 
account_number number(8) not null,  
register_date date not null, 
balance number(10,2)

constraint account_pk primary key(account_number)
);

create table deposit( 
row_nr number(9) not null,  
account_number number(8) not null, 
amount number(10,2), 
deposit_date date not null, 

constraint deposit_pk primary key(row_nr),  
constraint deposit_fk foreign key(row_nr) references account(row_nr) 
);

create or replace trigger aifer_deposit
after insert
on deposit
for each row 
begin
update account
set balance = balance + (select amount from deposit)
where account.account_number = deposit.account_number;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't list what errors you are getting or any other information that would allow for accurate assistance.... However the two things that stick out to me are both to do with

```
select amount from deposit
```

1) This will select ALL rows from deposit as you have not specified a where clause.  This will return multiple rows which wouldn't work in this context

2) You are selecting from deposit when the trigger is on deposit, this can cause mutating table errors so should be avoided at all costs.

Start by having a look at the examples at https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php

This shows that you can use :new.amount (:new references the row that has just been inserted) instead of doing the select so your update would look more like

```
update account
set balance = balance + :new.amount
where account.account_number = :new.account_number;
```

If there are further errors please post more specific information on the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks @shaunThe problem was as you explained.